# If $a^2 +3b^2$ is a prime integer, show that $a +bi\sqrt{3}$ is an irreducible element in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

If $a^2 +3b^2$ is a prime integer, we have to show that $a +bi\sqrt{3}$ is an irreducible element in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$.

Now $a^2+3b^2=(a+ib\sqrt{3})(a-ib\sqrt{3})$ as $a^2+3b^2$ is prime, so $a^2+3b^2 | (a+ib\sqrt{3})$ or $a^2+3b^2 | (a-ib\sqrt{3})$. Suppose $a^2+3b^2 | (a+ib\sqrt{3})$ so $(a+ib\sqrt{3})=q.(a^2+3b^2)$. Then $a^2+3b^2=q.(a^2+3b^2)(a-ib\sqrt{3}) \implies 1=q.(a-ib\sqrt{3}) \implies q \ \text{is a unit}$. So $a+ib\sqrt{3}$ is irreducible.

But if $a^2+3b^2 | (a-ib\sqrt{3})$ so $(a-ib\sqrt{3})=q_1.(a^2+3b^2)$. Then $a^2+3b^2=q_1.(a^2+3b^2)(a+ib\sqrt{3}) \implies 1=q_1.(a+ib\sqrt{3}) \implies q_1 \ \text{is a unit}$. From this how to show $(a+bi\sqrt{3})$ is irreducible.

And is there exists any prime integer in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$  of the form $a^2+3b^2$?

Comment: Sketch of the proof: suppose that $a+bi\sqrt{3}$ is *not* irreducible, i.e. that $a+bi\sqrt{3}=(p+qi\sqrt{3})(r+si\sqrt{3})$. Prove (using the rule that complex number modulus of the product is the product of the moduli of the factors) that $a^2+3b^2=(p^2+3q^2)(r^2+3s^2)$. As $a^2+3b^2$ is a prime integer, it means that one of $p^2+3q^2$ or $r^2+3s^2$ must be $1$ etc.

Comment: Otherwise, it is wrong to say that, as $a^2+3b^2=(a-bi\sqrt{3})(a+bi\sqrt{3})$ the left side must divide one of $a-bi\sqrt{3}, a+bi\sqrt{3}$. $a^2+3b^2$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$ but it doesn’t need to be a prime in $\mathbb Z[i\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan yeah now I have edited it